# Websocket (wss) sending/receiving wrong cookie for my domain with /path/

Tags: php, cookies, websocket

Im connecting to my own ratchet php websocket server on the same domain as my https website,

I have existing (different) cookies on [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and [www.domain.com/admin](http://www.domain.com/admin)

If I type in console `document.cookie` when on [www.domain.com/admin](http://www.domain.com/admin) i see the right cookie.

If I type in console `new WebSocket('wss://www.domain.com/admin','wamp')` and then look at the webdev toolbar network section, click on the wss connection (status 101) and look at the cookie -> "request cookies" section it shows the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) cookie,

And on my server, where i work with the sent cookie, its the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) cookie rather than admin one.

Im wondering if it could be something to do with the upgrade request/process , or any other ideas.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be issuing a restrictive cookie path, check the cookies via the Network Tab, not via document.cookie.

Comment: The cookies are in strict mode, the problem is when i start a websocket connection from the /admin/ path page, the front end cookie is sent instead. I have a cookie inspector addon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem with the help of wireshark, both cookies are being sent (to either a normal http page get, or the websocket open), but as they have the same name, if you look at `$_COOKIE` you will only see one, but if you look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']` you see both, a quirk of php.

So it would seem the php websocket library cookie parser guzzlehttp `httpRequest->getHeader('Cookie')` is also loosing one.